# How to Create Multi Screen Resolution sites in Asp.NET (vb)?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, vb.net, layout

Can anybody tell me,

how do i create website which supports various screen resolution & Multi browser support (i.e 1024*768 ) and others using asp.net...

i have developed website in asp.net (vb) my monitor resoultion is 1024*768 but when i try to access my site in other monitor having the resolution more than 1024*768 then the controls are unmanaged .... in the webpage...

What was the problem ? and how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Might be a good idea to post a sample of html/css that is causing a specific issue.

Comment: stop using `&nbsp;` to create layouts?

Comment: troll? New user with strange name, 1 rep, asking a question that seems at least mildly odd....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using css file to manage the layout of website. Using div id="" or div class="" to control each section of your site. And finally, text and image sizes are as important. Btw, if you have not already done so, use a masterpage in asp.net website.

Good Luck!